# Not able to set status Enabled for duplicated products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, products, status

I created a new simple product in newly installed **Magento 2.0.7**. The product is being shown in frontend.

When I tried to duplicate product, it was disabled by default (default behaviour of duplicate products in magento).

I tried to enable it from:

**- Editing product individually.** (There is an option in edit product section, which toggles Product offline/online)

**- From mass action (Change Status option)**

In both cases, magento is showing product as **disabled**.

**Note:** When I am creating new product, I am able to enable it.

**Note:** I have also checked for the same in Magento 2.0.8 also. Issue is same in this version also.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Check log file or report file for the error and try to sort out the issue or you can paste error here for me to reply you better.

Comment: No such log is being created. Only debug log is there.

Comment: Have you found any error in debug log? And have you installed any custom extension related to product functionality? if yes, try to disable that extension.

Comment: No extension has been installed yet. It is fresh magento installation

Comment: Can any one help me?